# Why is logic right shift behaving like arithmetic right shift in this code?

Tags: verilog, logical-operators

I'm building a floating point adder module and part of it requires 2's complementing and shifting value. The main module code is

```
module backup (x, y, z, clk);
input [7:0] x,y;
output reg [7:0] z;
input clk;
integer i;
reg [1:0] a;
reg unsigned [7:0] temp;
reg unsigned [8:0] temp2;
always @ (posedge clk) begin
a = 2'b00;
temp = 8'b00111100; 
temp = ((~temp)+1) >> 2;
$display("temp = %b", temp);
end
endmodule

module backup_tb();
reg [7:0] x,y;
wire [7:0] z;
reg clk;

backup m1 (.x(x),.y(y),.z(z),.clk(clk));

always #10 clk = ~clk;
initial begin
clk = 0;
#50
$finish;
end
endmodule
```

The output for this code is  `temp = 11110001` while intended output is `temp = 00110001`. Please explain what am I missing here, or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the shift right; it's with the expression `((~temp)+1)`. You are adding an 8-bit operand to a 32-bit operand, and operands get extended *before* performing any operations. Numeric literals are implicitly 32-bits. So the bitwise `~` operation inverts `32'b00000000_00000000_00000000_00111100` and then shifts it right. To fix it, yo can write:

```
temp = ((~temp)+1'b1) >> 2;
```